# Como obtener Fecha Actual del Servidor cloud Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, date, android-layout, timestamp

la pregunta es como se puede obtener la fecha actual del servidor cloud de firebase.

Les cuento tengo un `DownCountTimer` y necesito obtener la fecha del servidor, para así poder lograr que sea cual sea el lugar de donde te metas (Japón, Chile, Arabia, etc) el DownCountTimer tenga el mismo tiempo y finalice para todos por igual, lo único que se me ha ocurrido es usar la fecha fija del servidor.

Si utilizo `Timestamp.now()` parece que es la fecha desde el dispositivo, porque si cambio  la zona horaria del mismo, o la hora, entonces me cambia el contador. y lo que necesito es que así cambies el teléfono de fecha, o tengas una distinta zona horaria, el contador sea siempre el mismo para todos, espero haberme explicado, espero tengan alguna solución, y me ayuden con este problema, de antemano Gracias

Comment: puedes usar dependiendo de la version
hoy()
today()

Comment: Hola Heyson, saludos, podrias explicar mejor tu sugerencia, la verdad entiendo exactamente lo que sugieres, de antemano gracias.

Answer (score 2):

`Timestamp.now()` se puede usar pero solo para obtener la fecha del lado del cliente, su equivalente del lado del servidor para obtener el timestamp actual sería:

```
admin.firestore.Timestamp.now()
```

Para obtener este valor debes hacer uso de Firebase Cloud Functions

```
import { firestore } from 'firebase-admin';
...
const now = admin.firestore.Timestamp.now()
```

Revisa la documentación oficial de [Cloud Functions para Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions?hl=es-419)

Para llamar una funcion creada en Firebase desde tu aplicación revisa

[**Llama a funciones desde tu app**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#java)

Comment: hola Jorgeys, utilice tu codigo, pero...

admin me aparece en rojo (Cannon resolve symbol 'admin'

Comment: Es que tienes que usar Cloud Functions para Firebase

Comment: Hola jorge, vale no tengo implementado ello, dame un minuto y lo implemento, te estare escribiendo

Comment: Jorge, disculpa mi ignorancia, pero  el codigo es en java, creo que lo que me dices es kotlin o me equivoco.

Comment: @aAaDesigner desde el cliente no se puede realizar la obtención tienes que obtenerlo desde el servidor usando .js https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing?hl=es-419 y con Java o Kotlin llamar esa función: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#java

Comment: Vale jorge, estoy implementando el Cloud Functions y voy a testear lo que mas sugerido, te estare escribiendo

Comment: Claro que sí , trata de implementar la función en Firebase y su lectura en tu app, si tienes dudas puedes preguntar, la comunidad te puede ayudar en estos temas, saludos.

Comment: Jorge, ya implemente todo, ya esta creadoel archivo index.js, donde he colocado tu codigo, el detalle que no me queda claro, es  como traer esos datos a la aplicacion, es decir como me traigo el NOW que tiene tu codigo para la app, estoy leyendo lo que me orientas de llamar funciones a la app, pero no lo tengo muy claro